# PDE involving power of time derivatives arising from rate-dependent systems

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

The second law of thermodynamics can usually be mathematically formulated by the following inclusion
$$ -D_{u}H(u(t))\in\partial\Psi(u'(t)).$$
Here, $u$ is some physical quantity density, $H$ the Helmholtz energy, $\Psi$ a convex and non-negative dissipation functional and $\partial\Psi$ the subdifferential of $\Psi$. In engineering simulations it is often assumed that
$$ \Psi(u)=|u|^p/p$$ for some $p\in[1,\infty).$ When $p=1$, the system is called rate-independent and $\Psi$ is not differentiable at $u=0$. Such rate-independent systems have been well-studied by Mielke and his collaborators. When $p=2$, $\Psi$ is differentiable and the subdifferential $\partial\Psi(u')$ contains the single element $u'$ and we can solve the problem by well-kwon ODE or PDE methods. However, I am quite curious what happens when $p$ is other than one or two. Do such systems have a name and is there any existing reference?

Thank you in advance for any potential suggenstions!

Answer (score 1):

After looking for some reference I have found that such problems are the so called *doubly nonlinear problems*. I would refer to [this link](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%20doubly%20nonlinear%20Cauchy%20problem&btnG=&oq=doubly) for more details on the corresponding references.